# Storing 'session values' in MS MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting started in MVC3 with a jquery/js driven front end.  I realise that the paradigm of MVC is not to rely much on the concept of session variables and the like, instead using the actions and controllers to drive the user experience.  I have the situation below, what's the proper way to do it?

a) I have a little menu with a set of 'select exhibit' options - show summary, show user details etc.  Clicking one calls a controller (lets say 'rendersummary' or 'renderuserdetails') which returns a partialview back a certain div on my page.

b) I have a separate 'filters' panel, which lets you select how many records to include, etc.  In that, I have an 'apply' button.  When you click apply, I'd like it to re-execute the last action again (eg rendersummary) but now using the new filter settings.

I recall you could use HTMLRoutings or something to see what the current action/args are, but am not sure how you'd do this for the most recent partialview.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: In the end, I think a simple global javascript variable will be my approach.  Thanks for the comment Max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a special controller that get the data from the filter panel and redirect the call to the last action/controller executed. If you don't want to use Session to store the navigation's information, you can add some hidden input field to the filter panel and valorize them using js.

Comment: Hi - what would this controller look like?  I think your idea of using a hidden input field is an interesting one - but again, is that the recommended method or is there a more 'proper' way?

Comment: @Glinkot I do not think there is a better solution that will work in every case. I think you should choose the method by which you are better.